# Transfer data from Oracle 9i to Postgres 9.2 Database

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, csv, database-migration

I need to transfer data from Oracle 9i database server to postgres 9.2 version DB with job schedule.

Right now i have no idea on how to write job schedule at oracle.?

Excluding job schedule just i have created an single stored procedure at oracle to export each and every table into single csv file.Is it good idea to create CSV file here?

At postgres end used an stored function to import an csv file after truncating the table.How far truncating the table is good here?.I dont think its good approach.

Comment: I think it'll be better if this question is on [Database Administrators Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did.Any how i expect the more from here.